# iPhone's UIStringDrawing for multiple lines

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to draw a long `NSString` with `UIStringDrawing` and `linebreakmode` "word wrap". The problem is, that it only draws one line also with this `linebreakmode` parameter. Do i have to calculate this manually and split the string into an array to draw each line?

I don't want to use `UILabel` with `numberOfLines` stuff. I put emphasis on performance in the User-Interface (so I would pre-calculate that stuff).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really simple

NSString:drawInRect:withFont: